# Databinding on code behind works the second time

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind, 2-way-object-databinding

I am having an issue with the databinding on code behind. Unfortunately, doing the databinding on xaml is not possible since the binding source changes between different objects

The thing is, the first time I execute this line

```
hexview.SetBinding(HexViewer.RawStringProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("Rawstring"), Source = object1.ClassProperty1, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay });
```

it does not bind, but the second time it does.

If I add this code to the click event of a button and then I change the value with the UI, the changes are not reflected.

If i click the button two times, everything works.

On the output window I don't see any error. Any idea why this weird behaviour?
Any direction point will be really appreciated.

Thank you
Fernando

Comment: Can you show the code of your button click which changes the property?

Comment: "Unfortunately, doing the databinding on xaml is not possible since the binding source changes between different objects". It probably is possible. You just didn't invest enough time to learn WPF yet.